# このサイトは質問者に対して厳しすぎではないでしょうか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 話題の範囲

日本には既に[Yahoo!知恵袋](http://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/dir/list/d2078297622/new)という質問サイトがあります。このサイトには言語を問わず、プログラミングだけで一日あたり50件から80件ほどの質問が投稿されています。

このサイトにはスタックオーバーフローのように重複を管理するシステムや正しい情報が上位に表示されるシステムはありません。どんな質の良い質問でも回答が得られなければ質問自体が削除されてしまいますし、複数の回答がついた場合のベストアンサー選出がほぼ一人の人物で確定してしまいます。実際、回答と思えないようなものが投票によりベストアンサーに選ばれている例は多くあります。

そういったものも含め、知恵袋には23万件の解決済みの質問があります。

---

知恵袋のように回答が多数あればまだしも、スタックオーバーフローはいくつかの質問において質問を制限しすぎているように感じます。また、**安易にマイナス票が投じられやすい反面、質問文を改善する為のコメントが残されない**傾向があります。

事実、[英語版に存在する質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/2818869)を、[日本語に訳して投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6875/%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E)しなおしましたが、マイナス票が投じられコメントは残されていません。出版物では記載されているものを探せず、インターネット上の情報を頼りに新しい情報を探している場合（特に英語）、それらの翻訳は役に立つはずなのですが、そういった質問に対しても厳しいと感じました。

[ヘルプ センター > 質問にあたって > どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) において、

> 質問は妥当な範囲にしてください。質問の回答として1冊の本を想像しているなら、質問の範囲が広すぎます。

としていますが、これも制限に拍車をかける要因になっているのではないでしょうか。
知的な回答者であれば要約することはたやすいはずです。
ましてや、英語版では要約された回答に対して+1,000以上のスコアがついているのを目にします。

せっかくコンテンツを管理する能力があるのに、コンテンツが管理されていないサイトより質の高い質問が出ないのは不自然だと感じています。

Comment: 文章が長く、論点が理解されない可能性があります。ヤフー掲示板の話は、スタックオーバーフローとの比較であり本論ではありません。後半の問題点をもう少しハイライト・箇条書きをしてみてはいかがでしょうか？　ここに私が編集した内容を置きました　→　http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1877/4715

Comment: @ita_3y 現在の文章は一文が長いため、細かく改行を入れると折り返しが増えて読みにくいかなと思いそのままにしたのですが、あったほうがいいでしょうか？むしろ panzer さんの言うように要約や強調をした方がいいのかもしれません。

Comment: @unarist 自分もどうしようか悩みつつ編集しました（いくつか、読点を加えたりもしてみました）。もし読みにくくなったと感じるようでしたら、お手数ですが再度編集をお願いします。

Comment: 今の文章でいい感じだと思います

Answer (score 25):

自分はいくつか質問した結果、ここで質問するのはためらうようになりました。

推敲に推敲を重ねて質問しても、その状況になったからこその質問なのに「設計がまずい」などの指摘をされ、回答の足しにならないコメントを大量にやりとりして辟易しました。

思うに質問者と回答者では質問者の立場が圧倒的に低いように感じます。
本家サイトでは単純な質問ほどプラス評価されているのに、日本語版では質問へのプラス評価自体がとても少なく感じます。
気軽で単純な質問ほど美しいのに調べが足りず怠けていると写っているように見えているのではないかと思います。
昔のニュースグループのような新参者に対する排他感みたいな感じでしょうか……

少なくとも質問というのが大切にされていないという認識があります。
ふわっとした感想で申し訳ないですが、素朴で単純な質問をこのサイトでできますか？

なので、雰囲気を少しでも良くするように、まずいタイトルの付け方の質問やタグが少ないのを編集したり、単純な質問でもプラス評価するようにして過ごしています。（質問はしなくなりましたけど）

このサイトでは質問者をサポートして楽しむという使いかたもあります。

Comment: 大多数の人は真剣に回答していると私は思います。質問された方の疑問を根本から解決することに注力する場合、その質問に至った背景や、質問された方が既に知っていること、あるいは勘違いしていること、その他様々な情報が回答に必要です。そういうわけでコメントで追加情報を求めたり、聞かれていないことでも補足をすることがあるように思います。お節介とも言えますし、具体化された質問が誰にでも役立つQ&Aや、高スコアの質問になるのかは微妙なところですが。。

Comment: 現在の[オントピックの定義](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)の上でプラス投票のガイド「努力した跡が見られる」「実用的」と言われても、「素朴で単純な質問」にプラス投票するのは難しいかもしれません。だからと言って誰も相手にしないとは限りませんし、秀逸な回答が得られることもあります。

Comment: "単純な質問"に関する議論は、過去に [該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595/) でも行われていますね。「質問者の立場が圧倒的に低い」については、現状賛同できる気がします。一方で、他類似サイトでは「傲慢な質問者」という問題があるとも思っています。反対投票の存在が、質問者ー回答者の適度な緊張感につながるようルール合意がされるとベストですね。

Comment: 本来このサイトは回答が得られるサイトかどうかより先に、質問が頻発にでるサイトであるべきだと思うのです。
どの程度のユーザが質問をためらっているのか、ユーザ数、質問数、回答数、アクティブな質問のプラス評価の合計を見ると惨憺たる結果に見えます。より質問者に対して寛容でなくてはと思います。

Comment: 質問者の立場が圧倒的に低いって...それって質問サイトじゃなくても、現実世界でもそういうもんじゃない？有識者に質問するのに、ふんぞり返って質問してたら答える気なくなりますよね？このサイトでもそうですが、回答者は質問に解答するのが仕事じゃありません。なんぼ解答してもお金になりません。にも関わらず、時間を割いて解答を書いてくれてるのです。それならば、回答者に敬意を払うのが当然かと思います。だって、分からなくて困ってるんでしょう？もちろん、回答者もふんぞり返って答えるのでは無く、最低限のマナーは必要だと思います。`回答の足しにならないコメントを大量にやりとりして`という部分がとても気になります。@seoさんの質問って本当に十分な説明がされてたんでしょうか？可能であれば、その`回答の足しにならないコメントを大量にやりとりして`という質問へのlinkを提示していただきたいです。あと、`質問が頻発にでるサイトであるべきだと思うのです。 `とか`気軽で単純な質問ほど美しい`とかはそれこそmetaで問題提起してみると面白いと思います。

Comment: 質問者と回答者は同じ立場であるべきです。少なくともスタックオーバーフローはそういう文化で作られていると思うんですよ。うーん、うまく伝えにくいのですが、質問者の立場が低いというのは日本的な文化というか儒教的な文化を感じます。（例えば申し訳無さそうに質問する人たちを見ていると強く感じます）
ふんぞり返って質問するというのはさすがにマナーとしてありえないですが、学校ではないのだから（感謝こそあれど）立場の上下はないはずと考えます。
また、リンクですが、明示すると個人への直接的な批判になりますし、他のひとが、私の辟易したことを判定する必要はないため貼りません。個人的な感想として認識してください。

Comment: 確かに、SOの思想が「有識者に質問する」という形なのかは疑問です。どちらかといえば、同業者が集って情報提供し合うコミュニティでしょうか？そういう意味では某掲示板やスラドみたいに、ある程度フランクというか、互いに対等にぶつかりあえる場でもいい気はします。一方現状は「有識者の皆さん教えてください」といった質問が多く、「質の低い質問」が相手にされないのを見れば、やっぱり「回答してほしいからなるべく丁寧に、失礼のないように質問しよう」って感じになるのも頷けます。…とはいえ、そういうコミュニティってちょっと参加のハードルが高い気もします。

Comment: 聞いている限りでは"前提知識を開発者なら知ってて当然"な人と当たっている気がします。例えばDB構造がよろしくない状態で特定の情報を出すクエリを求めたら、DBの正規化を指摘されたとか…。また、フランクの基準も曖昧ではありますが、http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1900/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E4%B8%81%E5%AF%A7%E3%81%AA%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E9%81%A3%E3%81%84%E3%82%92%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B　：別の質問で丁寧な言葉遣いの定義について語っていました。某掲示板のノリかとは思いますが、相手の顔が見えない以上、ある程度"ご機嫌伺い"をしなければならないのではないでしょうか？文面上のやりとりでは相手の感情が見えないので、砕けた口調で対応したり、知っている事が当たり前のような態度は慎んだ方がトラブルも少ないかと思います。回答者と質問者の両方がいて成り立つサイトなので、お互いが歩み寄るべきなのではないでしょうか？

Comment: いま、 @豚吐露 さんの「有識者に質問する」「回答者に敬意を払うのが当然」という言葉がコメントされそれが現在この回答に対するコメントの中で上位として投票されていることにショックを隠し切れない。完全に同意ではないにしろ「有識者に質問する」という思想を支持している人間がこのサイトで投票をしている人の中には多く存在するということで、このスタンスを厭わないという風潮が平然とまかりとおっているという事実にあいた口がふさがらず、「我々が自治を行っている」という傲慢な考えがまるで霧のようにこのサイトを覆っているようで軽い恐怖さえ感じてしまうのは果たして私だけなんだろうか。「回答」サイトのルールから一歩でも踏み外した質問には主観的な感情に基づいた低評価が下され、質問の素朴さや単純さを貴重なものと思うよりもサイトのルールに従わせ、その負担に耐えられないものは離脱し、QAサイトにとって最も大切な「はじまり」ともいうべき「質問」が大切にされていないように感じられる。質問なしには回答は存在しないはずなのに……その感情が疑問となり seo さんという語り手の力を得てまるで火山が噴火するかのように抑えのきかない圧倒的な感情として噴出したように感じられる。質問者の無垢さ、圧力など知らない素直さ、これが大切にされないとき回答は輝きを失い、質問のという種はインターネットという土壌から姿を消す。

Comment: @猫カフェ 今この質問を見ている人はほとんどいないと思うので、コメントに書かれても独り言で終わってしまうように思います。当人にだけ伝わればいいという話でもなさそうですし。それよりも、回答として投稿したり、新たに質問として投稿したほうが建設的ではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 14):

スタック・オーバーフロー（英語版）ができるまで、[Yahoo!知恵袋（の英語版）はこんな状況でした](https://web.archive.org/web/20080430224308/http://answers.yahoo.com/info/scoring_system)（2008年3月のスクリーンショット）：

> [image: ヤフー知恵袋のポイントシステム]

1. **評価対象は回答のみ** 2005年の最初は、投稿者しか回答の質を評価できませんでした。2008年になっても回答にしか投票ができず、そしてプラス票しかありません。質問することを制限する要素は質問者の点数のみですが（投稿すると-5点）、質問者は回答を貰えばそれを評価するだけで3点が戻り、100点からスタートするので誰でも質の低い質問を20問投稿することができました。
2. **システムは質より、量を中心に設計** 回答を投稿するだけで2点をもらいます。マイナス票がないので、質の悪い・短い回答を投稿しても点数が上がります。点数と質はあまり繋がらないため、より多くの回答を投稿することで確実に点数が得られます。
3. **コミュニティのモデレーション機能はありません** 投票の対象は回答だけですし、プラス票しかないので、コミュニティで質を管理したくてもその方法はありません。重複している質問、訳の分からない質問があっても放置するしかないです。

80年代から様々なプログラミングリソースはありました。ニュースグループ、フォーラム等はありましたが、英語版Stack Overflowを作った[Jeff Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood)と[Joel Spolsky](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD)はそれらのリソースに不満を感じていました。同じ問題が繰り返し投稿されること。検索して目的の質問を見つけても、3ページ全部完読したのに回答がなかったこと。その問題を解決したかったのです。

英語版のStack Overflowが2008年7月末に生まれました。この時点ではほとんどのプログラマーがフォーラムやニュースグループを利用していたため、幅広いQ&Aが投稿されました。例えば、[C言語についての本のリストを作りましょう](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/)、[ジョーク質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)等が最初の一年にありました。当時のルールは当サイトの[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)のメインページにあります：

> #### どんな質問を聞けば良いですか？
>
> プログラミングに関する質問はもちろん何でも大歓迎です！ただし以下のことに気をつけてください。
>
> - 内容が具体的で詳細であること
> - 質問内容をわかりやすく説明すること
> - 誰か一人でも世の中の他のプログラマーに役に立つような内容であること
>
> この3点を満たしてさえいれば、あなたが初心者でもスーパークリエイターでも関係なく歓迎します。
>
> それから、聞きたい質問がすでに投稿されているか、まずは検索してみてください。見当たらなければ、遠慮なく質問を投稿してください。
> 後から重複していると分かってもノープロブレム。これから先、同じ内容を検索した人が回答にたどりつく助けになります。
>
> 自分の質問に対して、自分で回答しても大丈夫です。
>
> #### 避けた方がよい質問はありますか？
>
> 主観的であったり、炎上を招く内容であったり、長々とした議論が必要になるような質問は避けてください。ここは明快な答えが出せるような質問のための場所です！
>
> サイト自体についての質問があれば、[スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)でお聞きください。
>
> #### 礼儀を忘れずに
>
> みんな何かしら学ぶためにこの場にアクセスしています。お互いに尊敬しあい良いサイトを作り上げて行きましょう。自分より知識の少ない人には寛容に、スマイルを忘れずに。
>
> #### ごまかさない
>
> このサイトの第一のモットーは、正直であれ、です。正しくない情報を見つけたら、マイナス投票してください。
> そしてコメント欄でどこが間違っているかを具体的に説明してあげてください！  他の人の投稿を編集することもできます －
> サイトのコンテンツを編集を通して改善していきましょう！

1年後にメタができて、コミュニティでサイトの範囲・ルール等について討議し始めて、今の形まで5年ちょっとで進化してきました。予想以上に成長が早かったので、英語版は膨大な投稿を管理できるようにルールを厳しくしたところはあると思います。

当サイトは英語版と同じではありません。もし当コミュニティが幅広い質問を受け取りたかったら、それでも全然OKです。現在のルールが日本のプログラマーに当てはまらないなら、ルールを変えましょう。当サイトの目的は日本の開発者を支援するリソースを作ることです。皆様が日本の開発者ですので、私たちができるだけ支援します。

Answer (score 13):

使い分ければ良いだけの話かと...
個人的には、知恵袋のように、学校の宿題や仕様丸投げ、何を質問したいのか分からない質問が乱立するような質問サイトになってしまうことの方が問題だと思います。それを避けるためには若干質問し難い環境であっても良いと考えます。
また、質問へのマイナス票の投票しやすさにも疑問をお持ちのようですが、これまた主観ですがベストアンサーよりもプラス票が多い解答のほうが役に立つ場合が多いように感じます。プラス・マイナス票を投じ易い現行システムで良い気がしています。
確かにコメントもなくマイナス票が投じられている質問も見かけますが、もっぱら質問者が何を聞きたいのか全く伝わってこないような質問ばかりがそうなってると思いますよ。

Answer (score 7):

[引用されている質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6875/%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E)(※削除済み。末尾に画像が貼ってあります)の質問者に色々厳しいコメントを言った記憶があるので、個人的に当該ユーザーについて当時思ったことを書きます。
このメタ質問の本文には、

> 知的な回答者であれば要約することはたやすいはずです。

とありますが、回答者は質問者に奉仕するボランティアではありません。回答者がなぜわざわざ長文を書きたがるのか、一度その理由を考えてみて下さい。回答の動機の一部はサイトのシステムが提供してくれますが、それでも足りなければ質問者のテクニックで回答者の気を引く必要があります。このような観点で

> 質問は妥当な範囲にしてください。質問の回答として1冊の本を想像しているなら、質問の範囲が広すぎます。

を解釈すると「質問範囲を小さく分割して回答者が気軽に答えられるようにしろ」という意味にも受け取ることが出来るのではないでしょうか。本文では英語版の質問での評価について述べられていますが、該当質問は良質な回答に惹かれて質問の注目度も高まり、より良い回答が集まりやすくなるという好循環を呼んだのではないかと推測します。質問が無視されているような状況ではこのような現象は起こりえません。振り返って[日本語での質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6875/%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E)をみるとコメント欄に

> 表題の件について何を調べましたか？　そして、そこから何を得ましたか？努力の結果、表題の件について期待した結果が得られなかったから、不足している部分を補おうと質問をしているのですよね？ あなたが調べたものと、質問したいことの着地点を明確に定めてください。

という逆質問があり、対して

> 日本のスタックオーバーフローに不足している部分を補おうと質問をしています

と質問者が返信しています。せっかく質問範囲を小さくする助け船を出してもらっているのに質問者が拒否してしまっています。*マイナス票が投じられコメントは残されていません*ではありません。あなたが無視していただけです。サイト全体としてのクオリティ向上という大義を掲げるのであれば、質問の詳細化や自己回答などで率先して動くべきだったのではありませんか？

また別の回答のイニシアチブとして「自分の行動により他人が成長するのを観測する」喜びというものが挙げられます。回答者が質問者を識別している状況で複数回質問を行わないと関係ありませんが、該当ユーザーは抽象的な質問を連続して投稿するというようなことを断続的に行っており、当時のユーザーの中では非常に印象に残りやすい部類だったと記憶しています。私はそのような質問に2,3個回答し、内容に関してコメントのやりとりをしましたが、正直なところ回答文を呼んでいるのかすら怪しい押し問答で辟易した記憶があります。

あまり態度が悪いとかそういう悲しいコメントはしたくありませんが、この質問で触れられている事例を一般化して自己弁護する前に、自分の質問が他のユーザーにどう見られているかもう少し想像してください。目的が達せられなかったからいって荒らしまがいの投稿をするユーザーの心象が良いはずがありませんよね？

---

### 参考：質問のキャプチャ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 補足：日本語版の[該当質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6875/)は削除済みのため、2015/7/13現在は一般に閲覧できない状態にありますね。

Comment: @yohjp 指摘ありがとうございます。キャプチャを添付しました。

Comment: これは回答として最悪だ。ある特定の個人に対しての意見を述べている。このサイトをより良くしようという議論とは到底思えない誹謗中傷他ならない。そのため通報した。