# 新行動規範と競技プログラミング

Tags: 討議

スタック・オーバーフローでは、新行動規範が作成されていますが、どうして行動規範の改正を行ったかについては、ブログの記事（https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/）で明らかにしています。

また、それに関する日本語のニュースとしては、InfoQの「Stack Overflowをもっと友好的な場所に」（https://www.infoq.com/jp/news/2018/06/stack-overflow-welcoming）という記事があります。

明確な変更点ついては、InfoQの記事から引用すると

- “くだらないことを聞くな(don’t be an asshole)”から“歓迎する”に変わろう
- コメントに対して何かをしよう — もはや皮肉と卑下には耐えられない
- 新しいユーザが参加できるようにしよう
- ユーザの知識のなさを判断するのは止めよう(ここはQ&Aサイトなのだから！)
- 質と親切さとの間の誤った二分法を拒否しよう

「競技プログラミング」の質問に対してはいろいろな意見があるようですが、新行動基準に基づいてどう対応すべきか自分の意見を書きます。

まず、「競技プログラミング」の質問を「歓迎する」に変えた方がいいのではないでしょうか。
次に、「参加できるようにしよう」だから、「競技プログラミング」の質問ができるように変わらなければいけないと思います。

本家stackoverflowでどういう扱いをしているか調べるため`programming competitions`で検索すると500件の質問が出てきました。そこでは、「競技プログラミング」の言葉と「特定のテストケース」で質問がされています。

日本のスタック・オーバーフローでも、新行動規範になったのだから「競技プログラミング」の問題を歓迎するように変わるべきだと思います。

皆さんはどう思いますか？

これは、[「競技プログラミングの文脈で「WAがでます」と言っているだけの質問は意図がはっきりしませんか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2756/)というメタに関連した提案です。そこでの判断の基準をハッキリさせる必要があるのではないかと思って投稿しました。

Answer (score 3):

Yasuhiro Niji さんや nekketsuuu さんに賛成で、競技プログラミングに関する質問も歓迎すべきと考えます。
その上で何点か。

#### これは「オントピック」か否かではなく、「歓迎」するべきか（できているか）否かの議論です

今回の議論は、「競技プログラミングもオントピックである」という前提の元で、

- 競技プログラミングの質問が他の質問と同じようには「歓迎」されていないのでは？
- これからは「歓迎」するようにしませんか？

と問うものであり、競技プログラミングを「オントピック」にしよう、と主張するものではないのだろう（それは前提だから）と私は理解しました。

つまり、例えばクローズ理由で「〜が足りない」といった指摘が他の質問より厳しくなされたり、コメントがやたらと辛辣であったり、マイナス票が集中したりといった現状（があると私は認識しています）は良くないという価値観を確認し、改善しようという提案です。

ですから、[nekketsuuu さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2777/3054)の、

> 一方で、今までも判断基準が置かれていたのは「質問として成立しているかどうか」であり「競技プログラミングについての質問かどうか」ではなかったと思います
>   ...
>   議論されているのは ... 決して「競技プログラミングだからクローズしよう／オープンしよう」ではありません

という指摘は少し論点からずれていると思います。その「質問として成立しているかどうか」といった基準が **競技プログラミングにおいては特別厳しく** 適用され冷遇されていませんか？ と問われています。

#### 個々の質問は個別に丁寧に理解する必要があります

> 宿題質問同様、もしかしたら競技プログラミングに関する質問をするときに質問者が陥りやすい「悪い質問の仕方」があるのかもしれません。

そうかも知れません。であっても、

- 傾向があるからといって個別の質問が冷遇されるべきではない
- 「悪い質問の仕方」を指摘する際も行動規範が言う「親切」な態度を崩すべきではない

ということを確認しておきたいです。

> もしそういう陥りやすい間違い方があるのであれば、そこだけ抽出して競技プログラミング系質問向けの質問の仕方ガイドラインが作れそうだなと思い、

この場合、 **ガイドラインが「偏見のパターン集」になっていないか** 注意が必要です。
今後、質問者が自分の質問に当て嵌らない「偏見のパターン集」を見せられるようなことになれば、困惑するしかありません。結局の所ガイドラインがあっても、個々の質問を個別に丁寧に理解し、それぞれに応じた対応が必要です。

もちろん、nekketsuuu さんの提案は上を前提にした建設的なものだと思います。

Comment: 「競技プログラミングにおいては特別厳しく」については何か比較対象はありますか？「競技（プログラム|プログラミング）」や「AtCoder」で検索しても関連しそうな質問は数個程度しかなく、それらも「競技プログラミングだから」を理由に冷遇されているようには見えませんでした。今回の議論の発端となった質問が『個別の』事例として冷遇されている(ように見える)と考えるべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick サイト初心者の質問を不親切な形でクローズするに至ってしまうと、多くの場合は質問者が立ち去り質問も削除されてしまいます。 
今回の質問も削除され、[検索では出てきません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=AtCoder+ARC+057+B)。
とは言え、クローズに至った質問が過去に大量にあったという記憶も無いですから、主観の問題として冷遇されていないと思う方もいるだろうと思います。
私としては学習・訓練を目的として課題に取り組んでいる質問全般が冷遇されていると感じます。

Answer (score 2):

はい、質問をその出自で区別すべきではありません。競技プログラミング由来の質問かどうかは、その質問の良さに関係ありません。[宿題質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/19110)と同様、見るべきはその質問が実際には何を聞いているのかということです。

一方で、今までも判断基準が置かれていたのは「質問として成立しているかどうか」であり「競技プログラミングについての質問かどうか」ではなかったと思います。実際、リンクなさっている私のメタ質問において議論されているのは「自分の知らない用語があるからといってクローズするのはやめよう」「質問したいことをはっきりさせてほしい」「テストケースについてどう説明すべきか」など、質問として成立させるための条件についてであり、決して「競技プログラミングだからクローズしよう／オープンしよう」ではありません。

競技プログラミングがプログラミングに関する話題であることは明らかなのですから、クローズ理由を考える際には**競技プログラミングという性質を取り去ったとしても同じ問題があるかどうか**という議論をすべきですし、実際そういう流れの議論になっているかと思います。

また本家 Stack Overflow での扱いがどうなっているかについてですが、Stack Overflow Meta には以下のメタ質問が投稿されています (私のメタ質問でリンクしたものと同一です)。どちらにおいても、競技プログラミングだからというより、そもそも質問としての質がどうであるかで決めようという話に落ち着いています。

- [How to deal if the user asks for code in online programming competition?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278771/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta
- [Where to ask competitive programming related problems actually?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298212/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta

<del>最後に少し脇道にそれると、宿題質問同様、もしかしたら競技プログラミングに関する質問をするときに質問者が陥りやすい「悪い質問の仕方」があるのかもしれません。もしそういう陥りやすい間違い方があるのであれば、そこだけ抽出して競技プログラミング系質問向けの質問の仕方ガイドラインが作れそうだなと思い、私は以前のメタ質問をしました。このガイドラインの草稿は作成中で、近いうちに投稿予定です (時間がかかっていてすいません……)。</del>

<del>**追記1**　ガイドラインの草稿を投稿しました： [アルゴリズムの問題が解けないときの良い質問の仕方](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2778/19110)</del>

**追記2**　[mjy さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2780/19110)を読んで、これは「質問の仕方」の問題として捉えるより、「質問者と回答者のやり取りの仕方」の問題として捉えた方が be nice な対策ができそうだなと考えを改めました。質問者に責任を負わせるのではなく、質問者には寛容なまま、質問者と回答者のやり取りを良いものにしていきたいからです。既存の議論としては [どの程度コメントに丁寧な言葉遣いを求めますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1900/19110) 、 [建設的なコメントとはどういうものですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1992/19110) 、 [このサイトは質問者に対して厳しすぎではないでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1878/19110) あたりを参考にしています。(ただ投稿までには再び時間がかかると思います、すいません……)

Comment: mjy さんの回答にあるように、メタの議論をみると競技プログラミングの質問が他の質問と同じようには「歓迎」されていないと感じています。競技プログラミング」の質問を「歓迎する」かどうかを明確に回答してもらいたいです。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji さん、はい、競技プログラミングの質問も歓迎すべきです。そもそも元々私のメタ質問自体も「この対応は厳しすぎませんか？」というものであったことにご留意頂けると幸いです。おそらく Niji さんも私も同種の問題を想定していて、その改善方法を模索している段階なのだと思っています。私ははじめ質問の仕方を工夫してもらえば良いのではないかと思い「質問方法のガイドライン」案を出しました。しかし mjy さんのご投稿を読んで、これは質問内容の問題として扱うより、質問者と回答者の間のやり取りの問題として扱う方が be nice に近づけそうだなと考えを改めました。なので今は「質問への反応の仕方ガイドライン」のようなものにした方が良いのではないかと考えています。個別に丁寧に対応することは大事ですが、その方針だけだと過剰反応が今まで何度も繰り返されているため、もっと具体化したものにしよう、ということです。これは CoC で言われている「けなす言動や敵意のある言葉は許されません」ということだけでなく、どうやったら円滑に議論を回せそうかという話になる予定です。(書くためにまた少しお時間を頂くことになるかと思います……、すいません。)

Comment: 「この対応は厳しすぎませんか？」と思うのであればなぜ対応しないのですか？それで新たな質問、「メタ「競技プログラミングの文脈で「WAがでます」と言っているだけの質問は意図がはっきりしませんか？」の修正について」https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2782/ をしましたので、回答してほしいです。

Comment: @YasuhiroNiji さん、すいません、ご質問の意味がよく分からなかったです。私個人が厳しいと思ったことととコミュニティがどう判断するかは別なので、[私が投稿した方のメタ質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2756/19110)に寄せられた回答たちの vote に大きな差が無い現状、強権的なモデレーションはしにくいです。

Comment: 通報すれば、「すべての措置はモデレーションチームの裁量によりケースバイケースで行われます。」とあります。通報をしたのでモデレーションチームの裁量によって措置をおこない、どのように処理を行ったかをご回答ください。